# How do you move a LVM crypto swap partition from sda to sdb?

Tags: fstab, swap, lvm, partitioning

I have LVM configured for an encrypted home folder. Naturally this implies that swap falls into the crypto catagory. I have installed a second disk with a swap partition already ready to go and ready to be plug into the 'matrix'. Since I shortsightedly didn't consider LVM to handle the swap partition. I'm wondering is it possible to enter the new swap partition into fstab restart and be comfortable knowing it'll work. Or, do I have to continue with LVM?

===Edit for terminology correction===

Comment: This is probably going to be a question for unix.stackexchange or superuser.com

Comment: She's a toughy for sure

Comment: Could you post the output to `lvm dumpconfig`, `parted --list`, mount all volumes shown, then a `df --human` and then a `free --human`.  That should give us a bit more info to work on.

Comment: @Fabby I actually just reinstalled. However, seeing as this is a qustion that would interest many others. Could you outline the over all process. Not asking for high detail. Just a how-to in general for all?

Comment: I believe in TruCrypt and full drive encryption, so unfortunately, no I can't (not without a massive amount of work!)  ;-)